# Having trouble with input dimensions for Pytorch LSTM with torchtext

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, torchtext

## Problem

I'm trying to build a text classifier network using LSTM. The error I'm getting is:

```
RuntimeError: Expected hidden[0] size (4, 600, 256), got (4, 64, 256)
```

## Details

The data is json and looks like this:

```
{"cat": "music", "desc": "I'm in love with the song's intro!", "sent": "h"}
```

I'm using `torchtext` to load the data.

```
from torchtext import data
from torchtext import datasets

TEXT = data.Field(fix_length = 600)
LABEL = data.Field(fix_length = 10)

BATCH_SIZE = 64

fields = {
    'cat': ('c', LABEL),
    'desc': ('d', TEXT),
    'sent': ('s', LABEL),
}
```

My LSTM looks like this

```
EMBEDDING_DIM = 64
HIDDEN_DIM = 256
N_LAYERS = 4

MyLSTM(
  (embedding): Embedding(11967, 64)
  (lstm): LSTM(64, 256, num_layers=4, batch_first=True, dropout=0.5)
  (dropout): Dropout(p=0.3, inplace=False)
  (fc): Linear(in_features=256, out_features=8, bias=True)
  (sig): Sigmoid()
)
```

I end up with the following dimensions for the `inputs` and `labels`

```
batch = list(train_iterator)[0]
inputs, labels = batch
print(inputs.shape) # torch.Size([600, 64])
print(labels.shape) # torch.Size([100, 2, 64])
```

And my initialized hidden tensor looks like:

```
hidden # [torch.Size([4, 64, 256]), torch.Size([4, 64, 256])]
```

## Question

I'm trying to understand what the dimensions at each step should be.
Should the hidden dimension be initialized to (4, 600, 256) or (4, 64, 256)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation of [`nn.LSTM` - Inputs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.LSTM) explains what the dimensions are:

> - **h_0** of shape *(num_layers * num_directions, batch, hidden_size)*: tensor containing the initial hidden state for each element in the batch. If the LSTM is bidirectional, num_directions should be 2, else it should be 1.

Therefore, your hidden state should have size *(4, 64, 256)*, so you did that correctly. On the other hand, you are not providing the correct size for the input.

> - **input** of shape *(seq_len, batch, input_size)*: tensor containing the features of the input sequence. The input can also be a packed variable length sequence. See `torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence()` or `torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_sequence()` for details.

While it says that the size of the input needs to be *(seq_len, batch, input_size)*, you've set `batch_first=True` in your LSTM, which swaps *batch* and *seq_len*. Therefore your input should have size *(batch_size, seq_len, input_size)*, but that is not the case as your input has *seq_len* first (600) and *batch* second (64), which is the default in torchtext because that's the more common representation, which also matches the default behaviour of LSTM.

You need to set `batch_first=False` in your LSTM.

Alternatively. if you prefer having *batch* as the first dimension in general, [`torch.data.Field`](https://pytorch.org/text/data.html#torchtext.data.Field) also has the `batch_first` option.